# birt customized pagination and export

Tags: pagination, birt

We have successfully implemented birt viewer 3.7 in our spring based web application. We are running through an issue where our DB query is fetching  a large dataset (around 8000) rows with images (blob data) which is taking around 12 minutes to appear on UI. Can somebody help us implementing custom pagination and export in birt viewer so viewer can retrieve around 50 rows at a given point of time. However if user wants to export data in pdf or excel all of the data should get exported.

Thanks
Anant

Answer (score 0):

- Add an Integer paramter (required, with default value 50) to your report.
- append "limit ?" to your sql query.
- Bind the new parameter to your sql query, so the ? gets replaced by the value of the new parameter.

you can set the paramter in the url like this: `http://localhost:8080/birtviewer/frameset?__report=reportname.rptdesign&parametername=50`

or simply set it in the displayed Parameters in the web viewer.

Comment: This does help. But there are two things which remained unresolved 1. I have some other criteria in report as well which will remain constant throughout pagination. 2. What about export. When I export report it just exports records in given view and not all

Comment: 1. if the criteria are constant, where is the problem? 2. if you want an export open the report with paramter = 9999999 in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by putting this into the web.xml file:

```
<!-- Preview report rows limit. An empty value means no limit. -->
<context-param>
<param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_MAX_ROWS</param-name>
<param-value>50</param-value>
</context-param>
```

OR add:

```
__maxrows=50
```

to the URL, but it is probably more manageable to just edit the web.xml file.

Comment: Nope. This will restrict your records to 50 only.